# Check URL of websocket client - python

Tags: python, url, websocket

I have a websocket server written in python using https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server, and I was wondering if it would be possible to check the URL of the website that the client is using to connect to the websocket server?

As in, the website is http://websockettest.com/ and I would like to check in Python that the user is connected via *websockettest.com*, rather than through another website.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I guess with "the URL of the website that the client is using" you mean `window.location`, a JavaScript object which is available in a browser environment. There might be many ways to transmit this to your backend, but should this approach be secure? I am not even sure what "secure" would mean in this context. You'd need something like a nonce provided within the website you are delivering to the browser, and the JS code in that website should send the `window.location` value (the URL in the web browser bar) together with the nonce to the websocket server through HTTPS, and the backend needs to validate the nonce.

I guess you need to think about why you actually want to achieve this. Do you want to forbid foreign clients to connect to your service? This is impossible. Service access is restricted by authentication, i.e. by credentials. Anyone could, theoretically, implement his own client and, given valid credentials, use your service.